# Perl index function equivalent in Python

Tags: python, perl

The index() in Perl returns the location of a text between a start point and an endpoint. Is there something similar in Python. If not how can this be implemented.

Example : 
in Perl, I would write an index function to return the index of a string as follows

```
start = index(input_text,text_to_search,starting_point_of_search)+off_set_length
```

What should be the equivalent in Python?

Comment: an example with expected output would be better.

Comment: you mean `string.index(text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you can use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) to find the index of a sub-string inside a string :

```
>>> s
'123string 1abcabcstring 2123string 3abc123stringnabc'

>>> s.find('3a')
35
```

> **string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])**
>   Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Comment: can it be done when we do not know what we are searching for(using a regex to find the substring)

ex : m = re.findall('<a href="/(.+?)" title=',page)
but I want to return 'm' only when a particular condition is satisfied( like startpoint < endpoint)

Comment: @SyedMustafaZinoor Sorry i cant understand what you mean by *when we do not know what we are searching* can you show an example?

Comment: can it be done when we do not know what we are searching for(using a regex to find the substring)

ex : m = re.findall('<a href="/(.+?)" title=',page)
but I want to return 'm' only when a particular condition is satisfied( like startpoint < endpoint)

Comment: @SyedMustafaZinoor Pleas add this explains to your question with a sample input and a desire output!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "text" you mean string,

```
myString.find(substring)
```